# specialization of variadic templates with class templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, template-templates

Here's an issue I ran across while playing with variadic templates.  I have some code that uses specialization to count "interesting" types in a parameter pack like so:

```
template<typename... _Pp>
struct count;

template<>
struct count<>
{
  static const int value = 0;
};

// ignore uninteresting types
template<typename _First, typename... _Rest>
struct count<_First, _Rest...>
{
  static const int value = count<_Rest...>::value;
};

// add 1 for a pointer
template<typename _First, typename... _Rest>
struct count<_First*, _Rest...>
{
  static const int value = 1 + count<_Rest...>::value;
};

// add 1 for a reference
template<typename _First, typename... _Rest>
struct count<_First&, _Rest...>
{
  static const int value = 1 + count<_Rest...>::value;
};

// add 1 for an int
template<typename... _Rest>
struct count<int, _Rest...>
{
  static const int value = 1 + count<_Rest...>::value;
};
```

This code works fine, but I run into problems if I want to use the same approach to count class templates:

```
// add 1 for a vector
template<typename... _Rest>
struct count<vector, _Rest...>
{
  static const int value = 1 + count<_Rest...>::value;
};
```

The above code fails to compile, error is "expected a type, got 'vector'" on the line beginning with "struct count".  I'm also unable to something simpler, all class templates accepting a single argument:

```
// add 1 for a class template with 1 type parameter
template<template<typename> class _First, typename... _Rest>
struct count<_First, _Rest...>
{
  static const int value = 1 + count<_Rest...>::value;
}
```

This code also fails to compile, complaining of "expected a type, got '_First'" once again on the line beginning with "struct count".  Is someone familiar with a way to accomplish this goal using this approach (i.e. some modification that I can make to one or both of the specializations that will get them to compile and perform the desired calculation at compile time)?

**EDIT:**
I want the parameter pack for vector to be unbound, similar to the following code for a simple container wrapper with variadic template-template parameters that also specializes on std::vector:

```
// pass a container as a parameter using variadic template-template 

parameter
template<typename _Tp, template<typename...> class _C>
struct success
{
  // not specialized for any container
  static const bool is_specialized = false;
  // data member of container type
  _C<_Tp> c_;
};

// partial specialization of above for std::vector
template<typename _Tp>
struct success<_Tp, std::vector>
{
  // specialized for vector
  static const bool is_specialized = true;
  // again, data member of container type
  std::vector<_Tp> c_;
};
```

**EDIT**
Seems like the final answer is that what I want to do can't be accomplished, but I have found a way to reframe the problem so that I cans solve it.  Many thanks to those who helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want... yes, you can create a templated struct that can count "class templates", so you can write something like

```
 count<std::vector, std::map, std::set, std::pair>::value
```

but you can't mix class templates and simple typenames, so you can't write something like

```
 count<std::vector, int &, float, std::set>::value
```

The problem is that if you define

```
 template <typename... _Pp>
    struct count;
```

you can pass `std::vector<int>` to it, because `std::vector<int>` is a `typename`, but you can't pass `std::vector` to it because `std::vector` isn't a `typename`; it's a `template<typename...> class` (or template template) that it's a total different things.

You can write something like the following `struct countC`

```
template <template<typename...> class ...>
struct countC;

template <>
struct countC<>
 { static const int value = 0; };

// ignore uninteresting templates
template<template<typename...> class F, template<typename...> class ... R>
struct countC<F, R...>
 { static const int value = countC<R...>::value; };

template <template<typename...> class ... R>
struct countC<std::vector, R...>
 { static const int value = 1 + countC<R...>::value; };
```

The following is a working complete example where I've rewritten your `struct count` as `struct countT` for count selected types, I've added a `struct countC` to count selected "class templates" and I've added a `struct countV` to count selected values of a fixed typename.

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

// countC for templates

template <template<typename...> class ...>
struct countC;

template <>
struct countC<>
 { static const int value = 0; };

// ignore uninteresting templates
template<template<typename...> class F, template<typename...> class ... R>
struct countC<F, R...>
 { static const int value = countC<R...>::value; };

template <template<typename...> class ... R>
struct countC<std::vector, R...>
 { static const int value = 1 + countC<R...>::value; };

template <template<typename...> class ... R>
struct countC<std::map, R...>
 { static const int value = 1 + countC<R...>::value; };

template <template<typename...> class ... R>
struct countC<std::pair, R...>
 { static const int value = 1 + countC<R...>::value; };


// countV for for values of a fixed type

template <typename T, T ... v>
struct countV;

template <typename T>
struct countV<T>
 { static const int value = 0; };

// ignore uninteresting values
template <typename T, T f, T ... r>
struct countV<T, f, r...>
 { static const int value = countV<T, r...>::value; };

// count only int odd values
template <int f, int ... r>
struct countV<int, f, r...>
 { static const int value = (f % 2) + countV<int, r...>::value; };


// countT for typenames

template <typename...>
struct countT;

template <>
struct countT<>
 { static const int value = 0; };

// ignore uninteresting types
template <typename F, typename ... R>
struct countT<F, R...>
 { static const int value = countT<R...>::value; };

template <typename F, typename ... R>
struct countT<F*, R...>
 { static const int value = 1 + countT<R...>::value; };

template<typename F, typename ... R>
struct countT<F&, R...>
 { static const int value = 1 + countT<R...>::value; };

template<typename ... R>
struct countT<int, R...>
 { static const int value = 1 + countT<R...>::value; };


int main()
 {
   std::cout << "countC vector + map + set + pair                   = " 
      << countC<std::vector, std::map, std::set, std::pair>::value
      << std::endl;

   std::cout << "countT int + float + bool* + double& + bool + int& = " 
      << countT<int, float, bool*, double&, bool, int&>::value
      << std::endl;

   std::cout << "countV int, 1 + 4 + 4 + 5 + 7 + 10 + 11 + 16 + 15  = " 
      << countV<int, 1, 4, 4, 5, 7, 10, 11, 16, 15>::value
      << std::endl;

   std::cout << "countV long, 1 + 4 + 4 + 5 + 7 + 10 + 11 + 16 + 15 = " 
      << countV<long, 1, 4, 4, 5, 7, 10, 11, 16, 15>::value
      << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The claim "but you can't mix class templates and simple typenames" seems to be the key issue here; I've looked at the N3797 working draft a bit but can't quite puzzle out what the rules are, would you be able to point me to more information on this limitation?

Comment: @BDatRivenhill - Sorry: I correct myself: you can't mix class templates and simple typenames in the same template parameter *pack*. Obviouly you can mix create a templare class that expect single typenames and single template parameter. But when you create a parameter pack, there are different production rules (if I'm not wrong) and parameter pack can accept only typenames (`typename ... Ts`) or templates (`template <something> class ... Cs`).

Comment: @BDatRivenhill - Point me to more information on this limitation? I suppose that this doubt deserver another question and, sorry, but I'm not good in searching in the standard. I'm reading the N3797 you named but it's too complicated for me. I suppose can be relevant the different production rules (14.1) and the matching rule in 14.3: (continue)

Comment: @BDatRivenhill - (continue with rule in 14.3) "There are three forms of template-argument, corresponding to the three forms of template-parameter: type, non-type and template. The type and form of each template-argument specified in a template-id shall match the type and form specified for the corresponding parameter declared by the template in its template-parameter-list. When the parameter declared by the template is a template parameter pack (14.5.3), it will correspond to zero or more template-arguments"

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
// add 1 for a vector
template<typename... _Rest, typename T>
struct count<vector<T>, _Rest...>
{
  static const int value = 1 + count<_Rest...>::value;
};
```

And this?

```
// add 1 for a class template with 1 type parameter
template<template<typename> class _First, typename T, typename... _Rest>
struct count<_First<T>, _Rest...>
{ 
  static const int value = 1 + count<_Rest...>::value;
};
```

Comment: As with the other answer, this binds the first parameter of the vector to some other type in the parameter pack, which is not what I want.  See the edit added to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
template<typename... _Rest, typename... T>
struct count<std::vector<T...>, _Rest...>
{
    static const int value = 1 + count<_Rest...>::value;
};
```

Generic version:

```
template<template<typename...> class C, typename... _Rest, typename... T>
struct count<C<T...>, _Rest...>
{
    static const int value = 1 + count<_Rest...>::value;
};
```

Variadic pack matters.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I want to do because of the introduction of the extra parameter pack T.  I want the vector to have its parameters unbound.  See the edit to the original question.

Comment: @BDatRivenhill What? A template class does not represent a type unless you specialize it. From the working draft: _A template defines a family of classes or functions or an alias for a family of types_. You know that `std:: vector<int>` and `std::vector<double>` are completely different types, do you? You want to count something for which a valid specialization could even not exist? So, what are you counting in that case? Specializations ask for a type, I'm sorry.

Comment: The bottom line for me is: why does the specialization of "struct success" for std::vector compile and the specialization of "struct count" for std::vector not compile?  Understanding this would help me to see if it is possible to accomplish my goal here.